# IOS notification of wifi connection including SSID

Tags: ios, captivenetwork

Newbie IOS programmer looking for a way to get notified when the IPhone connects to a WIFI network.

i.e.
Notification for the following transitions:
3G to WIFI 
WIFI to 3G
WIFI to another WIFI

It should be able to tell which SSID I am connected to ...

This took about 20 minutes to figure out on Android, can't find a starting point for this function on IOS

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using the code u can get the SSID data of the WIFI you are currently connected to.

```
CFArrayRef myArray1 = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray1, 0));
NSLog(@"%@",myDict);
```

Answer (score 3):

[For getting notification of network changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685152/how-do-i-receive-notifications-that-the-connection-has-changed-type-3g-edge-w), you could drop [Apple's Reachability class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html) into your project.

[As for getting SSID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library), check out the solutions in the [System Configuration framework's CaptiveNetwork API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html) (documentation linked for you).