# How to know the number of devices connecting to current Wifi AP (Android & iOS)

Tags: java, android, ios

I want to make a app to count the number of mobile devices under the current Wifi Access Point.
But it seems there is no API for that.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried to solve this issue yourself. Your question as it stands now looks like a code request.

Comment: Ask your router or make a broadcast ping. You will get all networkdevices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you to get a list of connected clients to hotspot in Android: http://www.whitebyte.info/android/android-wifi-hotspot-manager-class

Answer (score 0):

What Api have you tried ? you can try this https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler. You can see [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083369/ios-wifi-notification-api) here as well.