# Receive notifications that the connection has changed radioAccesstype between 3G, 2G or 4G in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reachability, core-telephony

Want to implement a listener which will receive notifications on bearer changes, i.e. when the connection switches from 4G to 3G or 2G and vice-versa. Also when the network provider changes, e.g. when the device is in roaming, it may change provider from A to B and C.

Through reachability API's we can detect when the device switches from Wifi to WWAN and vice-versa. for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685152/how-do-i-receive-notifications-that-the-connection-has-changed-type-3g-edge-w)

Through the api's provided in [CoreTelephony](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony) , I can query for the types like the provided name and the current radioAccesstype.

What I am looking for is if there is a way by which I get notified when there is change related to the above cases so that I can perform the required operations instead of me having to query the CoreTelephony api's after some particular time interval.